# The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, distributed-transactions, msdtc

I'm using NServiceBus as a transport layer on a project.  Currently **both endpoints are on my local machine**.  I'm getting the follow exception :"The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)".

Again, this is completely local.  I've read all the posts I could find, and they all say the same thing, configure the DTC to allow remote Network NTC access, as well as setting "Allow Inbound" and "Allow Outbound".

I've set everything as such, and no go.  I've spent a lot of time looking into this and haven't been able to find an answer.

Another bit of info.  I was having this issue with all NServiceBus messages, but disabled transactions temporarily until I could find a solution.  My current issue is that I'm using the Request/Response paradigm with NServiceBus transactions disabled, yet I'm getting the error again.

Just to be clear, with Transactions disabled, all other messages work fine, but in this one Request/Response (Send()/Reply()) situation, MSMQ is still throwing an exception.

Hopefully whatever fixes this, will also fix the initial issue, but one step at a time.

Comment: Please let me know if I can provide more details, or frame the question better.  This question was down-voted within the first minute for some reason, with no feedback as to why.

Comment: Are there any other transactional resources involved like a database?

Comment: Aside from RavenDb, which NServiceBus uses for subscriptions and timeouts and which is also local, none.  Sql Server isn't involved in the transport layer at all. Just a Send() call in one ASP.NET application hosted locally, and a Reply() call in the NServiceBus message handler in another locally hosted ASP.NET application.

Comment: The Send() call completes, but an exception is thrown in the Reply() method.  Using the NServiceBus source code, I tracked the exception to MessageQueue.Send(), but it's almost surely a configuration issue.

Comment: Did you verify connectivity with DTCPing? Does the hostnames resolve etc.

Are you sure the queue used for reply is transactional?

Comment: DTCPing completes successfully.  The value of the Transactional property of the MessageQueue object is true, although I have NServiceBus transactions disabled.

Comment: Did you create the queues yourself?

Comment: I did not. NServiceBus creates the needed queues automatically at runtime if they are absent.  Although I did go through each of the queues and set all permissions to "Allow" for every group, and added anonymous users as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.  The cause was me disabling transactions.  After re-enabling transactions, the issue has been resolved.  Also, in my time researching this issue, I figured out how to resolve the initial issue that caused me to disable transactions in the first place.

Comment: "Also, in my time researching this issue, I figured out how to resolve the initial issue that caused me to disable transactions in the first place." I know this is quite a bit of time after the event - but any chance you can elaborate on the initial error resolution? I'm facing the same issue...